# Can OpenID Connect Scopes Contain Spaces?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, authorization, openid-connect, specifications

Does OpenID Connect support the quoting of scopes?

For example, is requesting the `openid` scope the same as requesting the `"openid"` scope?

If so, does this mean that scopes are allowed to contain spaces?

I tried looking through [this specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-basic-1_0.html#Scopes), but it is ambiguous on this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See in the original oauth2 [rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/inline-errata/rfc6749.html):

```
The value of the scope parameter is expressed as a list of space-
delimited, case-sensitive strings.  The strings are defined by the
authorization server.  If the value contains multiple space-delimited
strings, their order does not matter, and each string adds an
additional access range to the requested scope.

 scope       = scope-token *( SP scope-token )
 scope-token = 1*( %x21 / %x23-5B / %x5D-7E )
```

According to this, `openid` and `"openid"` are different scopes, and a space delimits scope names (therefore not allowed *as part of* a scope name).

##### Update

Note though that in scope-token, it explicitly omits %x22, which is the double quote. So `"openid"` is not a valid scope name. Btw it also removes %x5C, which is a backslash, presumably to make validation easier in authorization server implementations.